# В чём разница разница между лямбда-выражениями и ссылками на методы?

Tags: java, lambda

IntelliJ IDEA предлагает заменить лямбда-выражения ссылками на методы.
В чём разница разница между ними?

Comment: Пример в студию.

Comment: Разница в том, что метод референсы выглядят компактнее. Я иногда делал набор параметров у функции такой, чтобы референсы использовать

Answer (score 6):

Принципиальная разница вот в чём: лямбда - это всегда новый метод в классе. Если декомпилировать вот такой код:

```
Function<String, String> f = s -> s.toUpperCase();
f.apply("abc");
```

получим такой байткод:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      // байткод main

  private static java.lang.String lambda$main$0(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_STATIC, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      // байткод лямбды
```

Для сравнения, код со ссылкой на метод:

```
Function<String, String> f = String::toUpperCase;
f.apply("abc");
```

даст такой байткод:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      // байткод main
```

Каждая лямбда в байткоде превращается в приватный синтетический метод с именем вроде `lambda$0`, который будет вызываться через `invokedynamic` каждый раз, когда нужна лямбда. Поэтому IDEA и советует вам заменить лямбду на ссылку на метод - так байткод класса будет компактнее, а значит, класс быстрее загрузится в JVM. Само собой, для того чтобы ощутить такой прирост, нужны тысячи неоптимизированных лямбд, но в крупном проекте такое количество наберётся легко.

В остальном выбор между лямбдой и ссылкой на метод - вопрос вкуса и читаемости кода. Например, если в лямбде несколько строк, читаемость снижается, и код только выиграет, если лямбду вынести в отдельный метод, и использовать ссылку на него. Или, например, если есть класс `ClassWithVeryVeryVeryLongName` с методом `doSth()`, то лямбда `c -> c.doSth()` будет читаться проще, чем `ClassWithVeryVeryVeryLongName::doSth`.

Comment: Собственно вопрос не *почему* IDEA советует, а в чем *разница* между лямбдой и ссылкой на метод.

Comment: @RomanC но ответ все равно отличный

Comment: @AntonSorokin Дело не в том, какой ответ - отличный или не отличный, а дело в том, насколько он правильно отвечает на вопрос. Не всякую лямбду можно заменить на ссылку на метод, ну а как оно реализовано в байткоде это уже зависит от компилятора. То что нет между ними семантической разницы и является единственно правильным ответом.

Answer (score 4):

В лямбде вы вызываете метод, который принимает столько параметров сколько у лямбды с теми же типами. Поэтому его можно заменить ссылкой на метод, которая в свою очередь тоже является лямбдой.

Об этом более или менее подробно описано в [примере](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

> ```
> Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray,
>      (a, b) -> Person.compareByAge(a, b)
> );
> ```
>
> Поскольку это лямбда-выражение вызывает существующий метод, вы можете
>   использовать ссылку на метод вместо выражения лямбда:
>
> ```
> Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray, Person::compareByAge);
> ```
>
> Ссылка метода `Person::compareByAge` семантически совпадает с
>   выражением лямбда `(a, b) -> Person.compareByAge(a, b)`. Каждый из
>   них имеет следующие характеристики:
>
> - Его формальный список параметров копируется из
>     `Comparator<Person>.compare`, который является `(Person, Person)`.
> - Его тело вызывает метод `Person.compareByAge`.

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл этот вопрос на [английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487805/lambda-expression-vs-method-reference), где на него отвечает Брайан Гетц, Senior Java Language Architect в Oracle.  Выдержка из ответа:

> Обратите внимание, что нет правильного ответа. Следует игнорировать любого, кто говорит «всегда использовать ссылку на метод вместо лямбда» или «всегда использовать лямбда вместо ссылки на метод».
>
> Этот вопрос очень похож по духу на вопрос «когда следует использовать
> именованный класс, а не анонимный»? И ответ тот же: когда вы найдете
> его более читаемым. Конечно, есть случаи, где определённо используется то или другое.
> Споры о производительности или о
> подсчете символов - это в основном отвлекающие маневры, и вам следует
> их игнорировать. Цель состоит в том, чтобы написать код, в котором
> кристально ясно, что он делает. Очень часто (но не всегда!) Ссылки на
> методы выигрывают по этой метрике, поэтому мы включили их в качестве
> опции для использования в таких случаях.

Разница между ними только в синтаксисе. Используй то, что лучше читается.